# fetch and push the data in new table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have the table 'project','user' and 'role_mapping'.I want to to fetch the project_owner_id from the project table and push the user_id  which is fetched from user table and role_id=1 in role_mapping table.one project owner has multiple project.so I want to restrict duplicate entry. I want to do it in laravel controller controller.

```
project table
project_id   project name project_owner_id
 1             DEC01
 2             DEC02
 3             DEC01

user table
 id user_string
 1     DEC03
 2     DEC01
 3     DEC02

role_mapping table
user_id  role_id
 2        1
 3        1     

$heads = DB::table('project')
      ->join('users', 'project.project_owner_id', '=', 'users.user_string')
      ->select('project.project_owner_id','users.id as user_id')->get();
      foreach($heads as $head){
          print_r($head->project_owner_id);  
          print_r($head->user_id);            
      }
```

The below query fetched project owner id  and user_id.How to push the value in role_mapping table

Comment: Check the many to many insertions at https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models

Comment: Do you have model corresponding to users table?Can you please share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to refer to this one, using Attach, Detach in laravel : http://kaloraat.com/questions/laravel-attach-detach-and-sync-methods

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Like this way

Assuming your model name as `MappingTable`

```
foreach($heads as $head){
   $mapTable = new MappingTable();
   $mapTable->user_id = $head->user_id;
   $mapTable->role_id = $head->project_owner_id;
   $mapTable->save();            
}
```

OR alternatively you can pass `$data` array like this

```
$data = array(
    array('user_id'=>$head->user_id, 'role_id'=> ),
    array('user_id'=>$head->user_id, 'role_id'=> $head->project_owner_id),
    //...
);

MappingTable::insert($data); // Eloquent
DB::table('role_mapping table')->insert($data); // Query Builder
```